# Date/time variable not respecting if statement

Tags: php, date

I am running a program in which part of it iterates through a directory and stores the most recent date in a variable and the name of the most recent folder in another.  I have a series of alerts set up so that i can debug.

### Alerts Order:

- Expresses current sub-directory and time
- Then the variable with the subdirectory date dubbed "temp" and latest date .
- Then "update time" if temp is more recent then the "latest"
- Then "Time changed" if temp is more recent then the "latest"
- Then it expresses the new latest time and latest folder name associated with that date

My problem is through the first subdirectory this all behaves normal.  Then the second directory it gets messed up.  The first 2 alerts are expected (the second directory is older than the first by the way).  The third and fourth alerts are skipped (as expected). but the 5th alert shows that the latest folder variable has been changed to the current subdirectory (yet the latest time remains with the past iterated subdirectory time).

hope this makes sense....here is the code

```
<?php  
    $files = array();
    $latestTime = date("1900-01-01"); ///older then any of the folders will be
    $latestFolder = "none";
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./images/ISGC_images/') as $fileInfo) { ///iterate through directory
        if($fileInfo =="."|$fileInfo == "..") continue;
        if($fileInfo->isDir()) { 
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$fileInfo." was updated ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime('./images/ISGC_images/'.$fileInfo))."');</script>";
                $tempDate = date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime('./images/ISGC_images/'.$fileInfo));
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"."temp time is ".$tempDate.'and latest time is'.$latestTime."');</script>";
                if ($tempDate > $latestTime)
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"."update time"."');</script>"; 
                if ($tempDate > $latestTime) { 
                    $latestFolder = $fileInfo;
                    $latestTime = $tempDate;
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"."Time Changed!"."');</script>"; 
                }
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"."latest folder is ".$latestFolder."');</script>"; 
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"."latest time is ".$latestTime."');</script>"; 
            }                    
        }              

?>
```

**ANSWER**

Line 14 needs to be changed to $latestFolder = (string)$fileInfo; because a folder object cannot be stored in a variable apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're directly comparing your dates while they're still strings. This seems to be defaulting to alphabetical string compare, so you're saying "01-01-1980" > "01-01-1900", which may not hold for the next string comparison, just as "apple" > "pear".

Try it with the actual time comparison instead.
e.g.:

```
 if (strtotime($tempDate) > strtotime($latestTime)
```

Also this part doesn't seem to make sense:

```
if($fileInfo->isDir()) { 
    (...)
    if (file_exists('./images/ISGC_images/'.$fileInfo));
```

So even if it's a directory you do file_exists('folder'.)? Of course this would not be a file. To loop over the files in the subdirectory you would have to do something similar to what you did on top.

Try to work it out yourself with these hints.

Comment: It's worse than that. $latestdate starts as a sensible date, but is later assigned the string value of a date, using the format 'F d Y H:i:s.'. That's just *not* going to compare correctly for magnitude. If you *must* compare the string representation of dates, use 'Y-m-d', which yields strings like the OP started with. (`$latestTime = date("1900-01-01");`) Date strings like "1900-01-01" compare sensibly.

Comment: Good point on the original date. But although they do compare sensibly, I do think it's a good a good idea use the timestamps when comparing dates, it just feels a little more logical.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.  I tried what you both said and no luck.  The interesting thing is my first try and each of your responses yeilded the same results.  Based on the alerts it seems not to be a problem of comparison.  It says my first subfolder (2013 aug 12) is later then the 1900 default so it gives the message (time Changed!) but the second subfolder (2013 aug 13) does not show (Time changed!) yet it still changes the time.

Comment: @MingMan : Edit your script to alert strtotime($latestFolder) and strtotime($latestTime) instead. What have you tried? Echoing?

Comment: They come out blank if i add that.  I added more alerts at the end and the time variable functions correctly, its only the folder variable that buggs out(it returns blank after all the iterations).  Idk if that helps but i dont know what else to say.

Comment: @MingMan I added a bit in my answer about your $fileInfo. The logic behind your code seems to be quite flawed I'm afraid. Try to think about what you're doing, line by line. (seriously :) )

Comment: @Spork I edited my code.  The original code also iterated through each subdirectory and added all the pictures inside into other folders to be displayed in a gallery.  that is irrelevent so i tried to take it out(it was functioning 100% so shouldnt be a problem) but i must have missed a few lines.  Seems to be logical now right?

Comment: No.. your main if is still $fileInfo->isDir().. while you seem to assume $fileInfo is a file in the whole block!

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me @Spork.  I actually found the answer.  The current code works but it needs one change.  Line 14 needs to be cast to a string like this:  $latestFolder = (string)$fileInfo;